# В чем разница между этими способами создания двумерного массива?

Tags: javascript

Как объяснить то, что массив arr1 так странно реагирует на замену элемента?

```js
    let arr1 = new Array(3);
    arr1.fill(new Array(3).fill(false));

    let arr2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     arr2[i] = [];
     for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
      arr2[i][k] = false;
     }
    }
    
    
    arr1[1][1] = true;
    arr2[1][1] = true;
    
    console.log(arr1,arr2);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тем что первый очевидно ошибочен. Вы положили в массив три раза ссылку на один и тот же объект вместо создания трёх разных

Comment: Вы передали ссылочное значение для метода `fill`, поэтому он скопировал ссылку три раза на один и тот же массив: arr1.fill(**reference**);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй массив состоит из девяти независимых элементов. Первый массив состоит из трех копий одного массива. Изменение любого элемента ведет к изменениях других двух копиях.

Нажмите на кнопку "Выполнить код" в вопросе. Увидите, что первый массив выглядит так:

```
[
  [
    /**id:2**/
    false,
    true,
    false
  ],
  /**ref:2**/,
  /**ref:2**/
]
```

Один массив и две ссылки на него.

Answer (score 2):

Один из способов пофиксить.

```js
let arr1 = new Array(3);
arr1 = arr1.fill(() => new Array(3).fill(false)).map(m => m());

let arr2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  arr2[i] = [];
  for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    arr2[i][k] = false;
  }
}


arr1[1][1] = true;
arr2[1][1] = true;

console.log(arr1, arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Массивы и объекты в JavaScript передаются по ссылке, в отличие от примитивов. Это значит, что работая с объектом, и присваивая значение одной переменной другой, вы копируете не значение ("такой же объект"), а ссылку ("этот же объект"). Что приводит к такому поведению:

```js
{} !== {} // Это, хоть и одинаковые объекты, но не "один и тот же"
```

```js
let object = {
  foo: "bar"
};

let newObject = object; // Мы создаем новую ссылку на тот же объект

newObject.foo = "baz";
object.foo === "baz";
```